# Head Pose estimation with Opencv and Opengl giving weird output

Tags: opencv, opengl

I was trying Head pose estimation mentioned in this [article](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/10/17/head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-opengl-revisited-w-code/).
I am getting some weird [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cHZ8.jpg)!

Am I using old opengl dll's?

Comment: the article uses the old rendering style, so I doubt that is the issue

Comment: this happens because of the old version of the Opengl.